# Does $f'(x) > 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ imply that $f'(x)$ is converging to $0$ as $x$ is tending to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have a question related to another question which I asked today, where some people gave me two nice counterexamples.

Suppose you have a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ $, where $f'(x)>0, f''(x) <0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Does this imply that $f'(x)$ is converging to 0 as $x$ is tending to infinity?

Comment: Is $f \in C^2, C^\infty$ or just twice differentiable ?

Comment: Suppose it is just twice differentiable.

Comment: Since the second derivative is negative the first derivative is decreasing. Further it stays positive. Hence $f'(x) $ tends to a non-negative limit as $x\to\infty $. You can see that the value of $f(0)$ does not matter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.

Start with the function 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}
$$ 
on the domain $x \ge 1$; this is the upper half of one branch of a hyperbola which is asymptotic to $y=x$.

Next, translate this downward by a unit:
$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}-1
$$
so now it intersects the $x$-axis at the point $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Finally, translate this leftward by $\sqrt{2}$:
$$h(x) = \sqrt{(x + \sqrt{2})^2 - 1} - 1
$$
This function is asymptotic to a certain line of slope $+1$ (by taking the line $y=x$, translating doward by a unit, and leftward by $\sqrt{2}$). So, its derivative approaches $1$ as $x \to \infty$. And it satisfies $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>0$, $f''(x) < 0$.

Comment: Call me super stupid, but doesn't $\frac{1}{x}$ converge to $0$ when $x$ is tending to infinity?

Comment: Right. I fixed my counterexample.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I was so sure that this time the implication would hold, haha. I am fascinated by how fast you people find counterexamples! Thanks!

Comment: How to find a counterexample: (1) $f'' < 0$ and $f' > 0$ means $0 < f' < \infty$ (2) What if $f' \to 1$? (3) What kind of function has derivative tend to $1$? (4) ... details ... (5) Publish answer

Comment: Heh, my first try (see the edits) was completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably straightforward counterexample is
$$f(x) = x - e^{-x} + 1$$
We have
\begin{align}
f(0) &= 0 \\
f'(x) &= 1 + e^{-x} > 0 \\
f''(x) &= -e^{-x} < 0
\end{align}
but
$$f'(x) \to 1 \neq 0 \text{ as } x \to \infty$$

Comment: Thanks! Also a very nice and simple counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

How about $f:(1,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x) = x + \log(x)$? This has
$$ f'(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x} > 0$$
and
$$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} < 0 $$
but 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 1$$

Comment: If we agree on $f(x) = x + log(1+x)$, I am fine with this counterexample :)!